How to fix 'script returned exit code 15' when running Jenkins pipeline
I am defining a pipeline using Jenkins. I am working on a text summarizer project and using jenkins for CICD. After triggering the pipeline,in CD stage I am getting error as below:
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu 3.226.221.21 'cd /home/ubuntu/ && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mishraatharva/textsummarization/main/docker-compose.yml && export IMAGE_NAME=${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/textsum:latest && aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com && docker compose up -d '
Shell Script
1.6 sec
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu 3.226.221.21 cd /home/ubuntu/ && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mishraatharva/textsummarization/main/docker-compose.yml && export IMAGE_NAME=****:latest && aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com && docker compose up -d 
--2024-08-18 19:19:08--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mishraatharva/textsummarization/main/docker-compose.yml
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.111.133, 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.111.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 95 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘docker-compose.yml.10’
     0K                                                       100% 3.77M=0s
2024-08-18 19:19:08 (3.77 MB/s) - ‘docker-compose.yml.10’ saved [95/95]
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-stores
Login Succeeded
yaml: line 229: mapping values are not allowed in this context
script returned exit code 15
Jenkins 2.462.1

I don't have any clue for solving this issue:
I am sharing my github repo containing jenkins file.
https://github.com/mishraatharva/textsummarization
How to resolve this?

Thanks for you question! Please provide a [mre]. What's the shortest code/sequence of commands that produces this problem? That might require some experimentation, but it'll make it much easier for your post to attract high-quality answers.

@AndrewYim while creating pipeline I got this error. I pushed the code to github, triggered the jenkins I am able to see one image in ECR and this error as well.

Why are you running your shell command this way ? (one ssh command) ? use a shell/bash file to make debugging easier


Your error does look like a syntax error in one of your yaml files.

Make you sure they are correct using your IDE linter/formatter or
using tnis website: https://www.yamllint.com/ .



@naruto007 Check line 229 in your yaml to see if syntax is correct. Use the link YassineLbk put in above to validate the yaml file(s).
